# Connectedness of the set

Tags: real-analysis

I'm new to Real Analysis, so I'm struggling with proofs. What is this set $$E = \Big([−1, 1] \times \{0\}\Big) ∪ \Big((−\infty, −1] \times \mathbb R\Big) \cup \Big([1, \infty) \times \mathbb R\Big)$$ and how to prove that its connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of connected sets is connected if the intersection is nonempty:
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of connected sets with $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$.
Suppose we have separated sets $A,B \subset X$ such that $A \cup B = \bigcup \mathcal{F}$ and let $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{F}$.
Now suppose $x \in A$ and $B \neq \emptyset$.
Then we have $y \in B$, and as $B \subset \bigcup \mathcal{F}$, there exists $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $y \in F$.
But also note that $x \in F$, since $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{F}$, so $x \in F \cap A$.
Now I'll prove that if $F$ is connected and $F \subset A \cup B$ with $A$ and $B$ separated, then $F \subset A$ or $F \subset B$.
Write $F = (F \cap A) \cup (F \cap B)$.
Note that $F \cap A$ and $F \cap B$ are separated, because if $z \in \overline{F \cap A} \cap (F \cap B)$, then $z \in B$ and $z \in \overline{F \cap A} \subset \overline{A}$.
Contradiction, since $z \in \overline{A} \cap B$, but $A$ and $B$, by hypothesis, are separated.
But, if $F \cap A$ and $F \cap B$ are separated and $F$ is connected, by definition $F \subset F \cap A \implies F \subset A$ or $F \subset F \cap B \implies F \subset B$.
Finally, note that $x \in F \cap A$ and $y \in F \cap B$, so we can't have $F \subset A$ or $F \subset B$. Contradiction. Then $B$ must be $\emptyset$.

Now note that the point $(-1,0) \in [-1,1] \times \{0\} \cap (-\infty,-1] \times \mathbb{R}$ and the point $(1,0) \in [-1,1] \times \{0\} \cap [1,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$.
Then we only have to prove that each component is connected.

But you can see that $[-1,1] \times \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$, just consider the projection $\pi : [-1,1] \times \{0\} \to [-1,1]$. Then use the fact that $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected iff $I$ is an interval.
To prove that $(-\infty,-1] \times \mathbb{R}$ and $[1,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ is connected, you can use that they're path-connected and path-connected implies connected (proof [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Path-connected_implies_connected)).

I'll make the case $[1,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$:

Let $(a,b),(c,d) \in [1,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$.
Then $f : [0,1] \to [1,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(t) = (1-t)(a,b) + t(c,d)$ is a continuous path connecting both points ($f$ is a sum and product of continuous functions).
We only have to show that $f([0,1]) \subset [1,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$, ie, that $(1-t)a + tc \geq 1$ and $(1-t)b + td \in \mathbb{R}$.
The second is obvious, then I'll just prove $(1-t)a + tc \geq 1$.

If $a \leq c$, then $ta \leq tc \implies (1-t)a + ta \leq (1-t)a + tc$.
But $(1-t)a + ta = a \geq 1$, the result follows.

If $c \leq a$, then $(1-t)c \leq (1-t)a \implies (1-t)c + tc \leq (1-t)a + tc$.
But $(1-t)c + tc = c \geq 1$. The result also follows.

Comment: I'm reading the proof that union of separated sets is separated:
if $\bigcup\mathscr{F}$ is not connected, then it can be partitioned into two disjoint, non-empty, **relatively open** subsets $A$ and $B$. Now fix $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{F}$, and without loss of generality assume that $x\in A$. $B\ne\varnothing$, so pick any $y\in B$. Then there is some $F\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $y\in F$, and of course $x\in F$. Thus, $x\in A\cap F$, and $y\in B\cap F$, so $A\cap F\ne\varnothing\ne B\cap F$. Why is this a contradiction?
F is connected, so $F\neq A\cup B$, but how do I get a contradiction?

Comment: What's your definition of connected set? Cannot be the union of open disjoint sets or mutually separated?

Comment: F is connected if F is not a union of two nonempty mutually separated sets

Comment: Then note that $F = (F \cap A) \cup (F \cup B)$, so we only have to prove that $(F \cap A)$ and $(F \cup B)$ are separated. Suppose $x \in \overline{F \cap A} \cap (F \cap B)$. Then $x \in B$ and $x \in \overline{F \cap A} \subset \overline{A}$. Ie, $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$. Contradiction. It helps? I can edit my post explaining better.

Comment: Im a little bit confused with $F=(F\cup A)\cup(F\cap B)$, shouldn't it be $F=(F\cap A)\cup(F\cap B)$?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, that's it. Later I prove in detail if you're still in trouble.

Comment: See if you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if two connected sets have  a point in common then their union is connected. Use this to prove that the union of the first two  sets is connected and then prove the entire union is connected (by applying the same theorem again).

Answer (score 0):

$$E=([−1,1]×{0})∪((−∞,−1]×R)∪([1,∞)×R)$$

The first part is a line segment on the $x-axis$ connecting $-1$ to $1$.

The second part is part of the plane to the left of $x=-1$ and including the boundary line $x=-1$

The third part is part of the plane to the right of $x=1$ and including the boundary line $x=1$

The union is a connected set because you can join any point of the set to any other point via a path in the set.

you may have to pass through the bridge $[-1,1]$ if your points are in different sides of the bridge.